# Sitefinity CSS combining in MVC Layouts

Tags: sitefinity

In Sitefinity WebForms you have a ResourceLinks control allowing you to combine multiple, but what do you use in MVC layouts?

I'm not sure if the razor helper @Html.StyleSheet will do the job?

Adding all the CSS files to the Global folder in App_Data\Sitefinity\WebsiteTemplates[template_folder]\App_Themes[theme] will automatically add them to the site, but won't combine them.

We're working with Sitefinity 8.x and looking for a definitive way to compress and combine JS and CSS, but the pickings seem slim.

Answer (score 3):

With the move from webforms to mvc, Sitefinity didn't include specifically introduce a new bundler or something so you're left with essentially 2 default options, but they've seemed to have opted for approach #3.

1) Use .less and .sass to pre-process as part of your build process.

So in your theme folder you would have a `global.less` (or scss or sass) that essentially combines them using the `@import` directive. 
    Install a VisualStudio extension like [Mad's Kristensen Bundler and Minification VS Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40) (previously part of WebEssentials) and then define in the VS settings that it should compile and minify on build.
    Then every time you build or publish, your one bundled-and-compressed .min.css will be available for Sitefinity.

2) Second option would be to use default ASP.NET Web Optimization.

Where you define static bundles in VisualStudio and then use these bundles by means of `@Styles.Render` or `@Scripts.Render` to output them.

3) Lastly a new way has been added with the new Feather approach, which uses the current fashionable approach of Grunt to bundle and optimize your styles and scripts.

In the /ResourcePackages folder you'll already see a gruntfile.js file which has a task you can run which can then compile (and can be extended to prefix, bundle, minify, etc) your .sass into a .min.css which you can then add to your solution.

A sample can be seen here (https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-packages/blob/master/Bootstrap/gruntfile.js)

I'd use a combination of the above approach to receive the maximum result with Sitefinity where you use option 1 to have VS build out your core/base CSS and JS and then include them using Web.Optimization. 
Any additional page or widget related styles or JS can then be included afterwards manually through the css widget which gets compiled through option number 3.

Once you get more familiar with this new approach you can create and load optimized .css and .js on demand - even using a RequireJS approach to load them depended on the widget dragged and dropped on the page. RequireJS might seem out-dated given the latest gadgets and gizmo's but with v9.0 its still being used by Sitefinity itself to add inline-editing functionality.

Let me know if you need more info on option 3, I'm happy to extend my answer with some code snippets, or sample scripts on how I've tailored them.